# Shasum check gives long list of errors

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

The Installation Guide says:

> **64-bit**
>
> Running the following command in your terminal:
>
> ```
> shasum -a 256 -c elementaryos-freya-amd64.20150411.iso
> ```
>
> should produce the output:
>
> ```
> a7b8edfe95eb1c12745e02c63f830cad06ee756f552cba1cdca7bc30b7ca39e7
> ```

I run the command and get:

```
./.disk/base_installable: FAILED open or read
./.disk/casper-uuid-3.16.0-34-generic: FAILED open or read
./.disk/casper-uuid-generic: FAILED open or read
./.disk/cd_type: FAILED open or read
./.disk/info: FAILED open or read
./.disk/release_notes_url: FAILED open or read
./EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI: FAILED open or read
./EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi: FAILED open or read
./README.diskdefines: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/efi.img: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/font.pf2: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/grub.cfg: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/loopback.cfg: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/acpi.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/adler32.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ahci.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/all_video.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/aout.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/appleldr.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/archelp.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/at_keyboard.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ata.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/backtrace.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/bfs.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/bitmap.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/bitmap_scale.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/blocklist.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/boot.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/bsd.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/btrfs.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/bufio.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cat.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cbfs.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cbls.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cbmemc.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cbtable.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cbtime.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/chain.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cmdline_cat_test.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cmp.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/command.lst: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cpio.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cpio_be.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cpuid.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/crc64.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/crypto.lst: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/crypto.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cryptodisk.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cs5536.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/date.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/datehook.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/datetime.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/disk.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/diskfilter.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/div_test.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/dm_nv.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/echo.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/efi_gop.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/efi_uga.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/efifwsetup.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/efinet.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ehci.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/elf.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/eval.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/exfat.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/exfctest.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ext2.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/fat.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/file.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/fixvideo.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/font.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/fs.lst: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_arcfour.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_blowfish.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_camellia.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_cast5.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_crc.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_des.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_dsa.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_idea.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_md4.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_md5.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_rfc2268.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_rijndael.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_rmd160.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_rsa.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_seed.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_serpent.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_sha1.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_sha256.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_sha512.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_tiger.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_twofish.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_whirlpool.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/geli.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gettext.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gfxmenu.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gfxterm.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gfxterm_background.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gfxterm_menu.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gptsync.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.cfg: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gzio.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/halt.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/hashsum.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/hdparm.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/help.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/hexdump.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/hfs.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/hfsplus.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/hfspluscomp.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/http.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/iorw.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/jfs.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/jpeg.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/keylayouts.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/keystatus.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ldm.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/legacy_password_test.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/legacycfg.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/linux.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/linux16.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/linuxefi.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/loadbios.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/loadenv.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/loopback.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ls.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lsacpi.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lsefi.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lsefimmap.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lsefisystab.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lsmmap.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lspci.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lssal.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/luks.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lvm.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lzopio.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/macbless.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/macho.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/mdraid09.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/mdraid09_be.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/mdraid1x.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/memrw.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minicmd.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minix2.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minix2_be.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minix3.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minix3_be.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minix_be.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/mmap.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/moddep.lst: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/morse.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/mpi.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/msdospart.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/multiboot.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/multiboot2.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/nativedisk.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/net.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/newc.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ntfs.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ntfscomp.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/odc.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/offsetio.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ohci.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_acorn.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_amiga.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_apple.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_bsd.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_dfly.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_dvh.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_gpt.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_msdos.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_plan.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_sun.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_sunpc.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/partmap.lst: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/parttool.lst: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/parttool.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/password.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/password_pbkdf2.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/pata.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/pbkdf2.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/pbkdf2_test.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/pcidump.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/play.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/png.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/priority_queue.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/probe.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/procfs.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/progress.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/raid5rec.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/raid6rec.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/read.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/reboot.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/regexp.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/reiserfs.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/relocator.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/romfs.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/scsi.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/serial.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/setjmp.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/setjmp_test.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/setpci.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/signature_test.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/sleep.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/sleep_test.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/spkmodem.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/squash4.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/syslinuxcfg.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/terminal.lst: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/terminal.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/terminfo.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/test.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/test_blockarg.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/testload.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/testspeed.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/tftp.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/tga.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/time.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/tr.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/trig.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/true.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/udf.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ufs1.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ufs1_be.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ufs2.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/uhci.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usb.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usb_keyboard.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usbms.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usbserial_common.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usbserial_ftdi.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usbserial_pl2303.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usbserial_usbdebug.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usbtest.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/verify.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/video.lst: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/video.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/video_bochs.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/video_cirrus.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/video_colors.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/video_fb.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/videoinfo.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/videotest.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/videotest_checksum.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/xfs.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/xnu.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/xnu_uuid.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/xnu_uuid_test.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/xzio.mod: FAILED open or read
./boot/grub/x86_64-efi/zfscrypt.mod: FAILED open or read
./casper/filesystem.manifest: FAILED open or read
./casper/filesystem.manifest-remove: FAILED open or read
./casper/filesystem.size: FAILED open or read
./casper/filesystem.squashfs: FAILED open or read
./casper/initrd.lz: FAILED open or read
./casper/memtest: FAILED open or read
./casper/vmlinuz: FAILED open or read
./dists/trusty/Release: FAILED open or read
./dists/trusty/Release.gpg: FAILED open or read
./dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz: FAILED open or read
./dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Release: FAILED open or read
./dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz: FAILED open or read
./dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Release: FAILED open or read
./dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz: FAILED open or read
./dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Release: FAILED open or read
./dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz: FAILED open or read
./dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Release: FAILED open or read
./install/mt86plus: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/16x16.fnt: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/access.pcx: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/adtxt.cfg: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/am.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/ast.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/back.jpg: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/be.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/bg.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/blank.pcx: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/bootlogo: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/bs.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/ca.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/chain.c32: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/cs.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/da.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/de.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/el.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/en.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/eo.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/es.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/et.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/eu.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/exithelp.cfg: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/fa.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/fi.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/fr.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/ga.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/gfxboot.c32: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/gfxboot.cfg: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/gl.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/he.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/hr.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/hu.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/id.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/is.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/isolinux.cfg: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/it.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/ja.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/ka.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/kk.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/kn.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/ko.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/ku.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/langlist: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/lo.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/lt.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/lv.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/menu.cfg: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/mk.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/mr.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/nb.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/nl.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/nn.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/pl.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/prompt.cfg: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/pt.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/pt_BR.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/ro.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/ru.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/si.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/sk.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/sl.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/splash.pcx: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/splash.png: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/sq.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/sr.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/stdmenu.cfg: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/sv.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/te.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/tl.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/tr.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/txt.cfg: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/uk.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/vesamenu.c32: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/vi.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/zh_CN.tr: FAILED open or read
./isolinux/zh_TW.tr: FAILED open or read
./pics/blue-lowerleft.png: FAILED open or read
./pics/blue-lowerright.png: FAILED open or read
./pics/blue-upperleft.png: FAILED open or read
./pics/blue-upperright.png: FAILED open or read
./pics/debian.jpg: FAILED open or read
./pics/logo-50.jpg: FAILED open or read
./pics/red-lowerleft.png: FAILED open or read
./pics/red-lowerright.png: FAILED open or read
./pics/red-upperleft.png: FAILED open or read
./pics/red-upperright.png: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_018-2_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04_all.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/e/efibootmgr/efibootmgr_0.5.4-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/f/fakeroot/libfakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/g/grub2-signed/grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.34.1+2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/g/grub2/grub-efi-amd64-bin_2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/g/grub2/grub-efi-amd64_2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/g/grub2/grub-efi_2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/l/lupin/lupin-support_0.55_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/m/mouseemu/mouseemu_0.16-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/s/secureboot-db/secureboot-db_1.1_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/s/setserial/setserial_2.17-48_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/s/shim-signed/shim-signed_1.6+0.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/s/shim/shim_0.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/u/ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu/oem-config-slideshow-ubuntu_83.1_all.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/u/ubiquity/oem-config-gtk_2.18.8.6_all.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/u/ubiquity/oem-config_2.18.8.6_all.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/u/user-setup/user-setup_1.48ubuntu2_all.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/w/wvdial/wvdial_1.61-4.1_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/w/wvstreams/libuniconf4.6_4.6.1-7_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/w/wvstreams/libwvstreams4.6-base_4.6.1-7_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/main/w/wvstreams/libwvstreams4.6-extras_4.6.1-7_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
./pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb: FAILED open or read
    101 restricted/binary-i386/Release: FAILED open or read
     20 restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz: FAILED open or read
      0 restricted/binary-i386/Packages: FAILED open or read
    102 restricted/binary-amd64/Release: FAILED open or read
    749 restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz: FAILED open or read
   1199 restricted/binary-amd64/Packages: FAILED open or read
     95 main/binary-i386/Release: FAILED open or read
     20 main/binary-i386/Packages.gz: FAILED open or read
      0 main/binary-i386/Packages: FAILED open or read
     96 main/binary-amd64/Release: FAILED open or read
  10320 main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz: FAILED open or read
  29960 main/binary-amd64/Packages: FAILED open or read
    101 restricted/binary-i386/Release: FAILED open or read
     20 restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz: FAILED open or read
      0 restricted/binary-i386/Packages: FAILED open or read
    102 restricted/binary-amd64/Release: FAILED open or read
    749 restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz: FAILED open or read
   1199 restricted/binary-amd64/Packages: FAILED open or read
     95 main/binary-i386/Release: FAILED open or read
     20 main/binary-i386/Packages.gz: FAILED open or read
      0 main/binary-i386/Packages: FAILED open or read
     96 main/binary-amd64/Release: FAILED open or read
  10320 main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz: FAILED open or read
  29960 main/binary-amd64/Packages: FAILED open or read
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `shasum -a 256 elementaryos-freya-amd64.20150411.iso`

The `-c` flag shouldn't be in there.

Comment: I submitted an issue for this to the web developers. See https://github.com/elementary/mvp/issues/821.

Comment: Aaand it's fixed! Awesome to see the gears moving so fast.